# AudioKit: How to capture application output as an input

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, audiokit

I have an Objective-C application that I'm trying to add a means to record output generated by the application to disk. I've added a Swift bridge to my app and have currently got the epic-looking [AudioKit Framework](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit) hooked-up.

**How might I capture my application's audio output and dump it to disk?**

Solutions using AudioKit would be nice, but really anything Swift or Objective-C works.

Ideally, I'd mix different input sources (My app's output, plus default the default system input channel), but whatever.

I'm not convinced this is actually possible in AudioKit. I've searched for hours on this. A while ago, I did have a bit of Objective-C code that did manage to record to disk, but it was kind of laggy and seemed to only record the last few seconds before I closed the recording session.

Comment: AudioKit can record its audio output, so how hard would it be to get your application either generating the audio via AudioKit or establish the application as an input (like a microphone) to AudioKit, from which it could be recorded.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka - I'm quite the n00b when it comes to Audio. The audio output of my app comes from [NSSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer). This class does support output to file, or to System Default Out, so maybe I can do something with the file. Any tips, sage Audio Wizard?

Comment: Apple has made it exceedingly difficult to route speech synthesis output for further processing. I had a number of project ideas that were killed by this problem. We've talked about adding an open source speech synthesizer to AudioKit.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka - Are you aware of any means within a Swift or Objective-C app for redirecting any output from the app? I suppose you've basically already answered this. Something weird is that if you install the [movavi recorder](https://www.movavi.com/mac-video-recorder/), you end up with a system-wide audio input channel that's essentially a copy of what's flying out of the default output. I'd assume something like that would require a kext and SIP would sink it, but I've used it on Sierra, maybe even HS. Sigh, this subject-area feels unnecessarily hindered.